# Compares times between players in CS:GO

Tags: php, html

The program is meant to compare values between the two datas given and see who has beaten the map faster and by how much. Formatting is set to MM:SS:SU. It looks REALLY sloppy right now and I'm sure it can be improved.

[Working example](http://repeatercreeper.me/projects/CS%20Compare)

```
<?php
    $yWin = 0;
    $eWin = 0;

    $yourTimeTot = [];
    $enemyTimeTot = [];
    if (isset($_POST['subCompare'])) {
        $timeList = trim($_POST['yTime']);
        $timeList = explode("\n", $timeList);
        $timeList2 = trim($_POST['eTime']);
        $timeList2 = explode("\n", $timeList2);
        foreach ($timeList as $time) {
            $partials = explode(", ", $time);
            array_push($yourTimeTot, $partials);
        }
        foreach ($timeList2 as $time) {
            $partials = explode(", ", $time);
            array_push($enemyTimeTot, $partials);
        }
    }

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($yourTimeTot); $j++) {
        $yourTime = str_replace(":", "", substr($yourTimeTot[$j][1], 6));
        $enemTime = str_replace(":", "", substr($enemyTimeTot[$j][1], 6));

        $ext = "";
        $lenStr = strlen(str_replace("-", "", ($enemTime - $yourTime)));
        if ($lenStr != 6) {
            for ($k = $lenStr; $k != 6; $k++) {
                $ext .= "0";
            }
        }

        $z = $ext . str_replace("-", "", ($enemTime - $yourTime));
        $z = str_split($z, 2);

        $timeZ = implode(":", $z);
        if (($yourTime - $enemTime) < 0) {
            echo "You win by: " . $timeZ . "<br>";
            $yWin += 1;
        } else {
            echo "Enemy wins by: " . $timeZ . "<br>";
            $eWin += 1;
        }
    }

    echo "<hr>";
    print("Your Total win: {$yWin}<br>");
    print("Enemy Total win: {$eWin}");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>CS Compare</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method='POST'>
            Your Time:<br><textarea style='width: 50%;' name='yTime'></textarea>
            <hr>
            Enemy Time: <br><textarea style='width: 50%;' name='eTime'></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type='submit' value='Compare' name='subCompare'/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

DATA:

> ```
> YOUR TIME:
> surf_ace_fix, Time: 00:51:85, Rank: 281/2635
> surf_aircontrol_ksf, Time: 00:44:02, Rank: 231/8792
> surf_akai_final, Time: 00:41:76, Rank: 44/2313
> surf_amplitude_light, Time: 01:19:87, Rank: 27/48
> surf_and_destroy, Time: 00:37:31, Rank: 76/494
> surf_annoyance_njv, Time: 07:36:09, Rank: 26/47
> surf_autism, Time: 00:44:33, Rank: 80/403
> surf_aweles, Time: 00:49:30, Rank: 44/215
> surf_beginner, Time: 00:51:49, Rank: 354/5116
> surf_borderlands, Time: 01:46:47, Rank: 55/232
> surf_calycate2, Time: 00:56:53, Rank: 38/104
> surf_calycate_csgo, Time: 00:39:30, Rank: 132/519
> surf_classics, Time: 13:10:93, Rank: 124/710
> surf_colors_beta1, Time: 01:35:34, Rank: 15/146
> surf_colours, Time: 01:40:81, Rank: 81/2189
> surf_colum_up, Time: 00:33:55, Rank: 30/1060
> surf_delusional_, Time: 01:21:28, Rank: 18/169
> surf_derpis_ksf, Time: 01:24:55, Rank: 182/3672
> surf_eclipse, Time: 01:29:03, Rank: 82/109
> surf_ethereal, Time: 01:45:44, Rank: 210/368
> surf_forbidden_ways_ksf, Time: 01:16:80, Rank: 182/1056
> surf_funhouse_njv, Time: 01:19:69, Rank: 223/927
> surf_grassland, Time: 00:49:27, Rank: 186/597
> surf_how2surf, Time: 01:30:87, Rank: 21/317
> surf_hurrr, Time: 00:47:48, Rank: 26/71
> surf_kitsune, Time: 01:15:69, Rank: 334/3654
> surf_kz_protraining, Time: 04:04:25, Rank: 41/181
> surf_leet_xl_beta7z_, Time: 00:17:14, Rank: 312/6755
> surf_legends_lite_gfl, Time: 00:33:17, Rank: 131/1676
> surf_lessons, Time: 00:54:75, Rank: 193/1397
> surf_life_of_duck_go, Time: 00:48:25, Rank: 89/3080
> surf_lullaby_ksf, Time: 01:08:16, Rank: 234/676
> surf_lux, Time: 00:38:48, Rank: 313/2668
> surf_me, Time: 02:17:73, Rank: 34/236
> surf_mesa, Time: 00:57:42, Rank: 702/6575
> surf_minuet_v1p, Time: 00:46:04, Rank: 131/1434
> surf_mom, Time: 00:50:69, Rank: 288/2960
> surf_neo_njv, Time: 00:46:37, Rank: 62/74
> surf_network_2008_final, Time: 00:38:13, Rank: 19/109
> surf_newb_hazard_r1, Time: 00:25:79, Rank: 418/992
> surf_noob, Time: 00:28:10, Rank: 21/74
> surf_olympics_sns, Time: 02:46:12, Rank: 53/102
> surf_oma, Time: 00:55:08, Rank: 17/96
> surf_pox, Time: 00:32:81, Rank: 148/2086
> surf_prelude_ksf, Time: 00:51:37, Rank: 159/611
> surf_presmon_fix, Time: 01:29:89, Rank: 24/68
> surf_prime_time_r3vamp, Time: 00:15:67, Rank: 186/2091
> surf_rebel_resistance_njv, Time: 00:27:03, Rank: 213/4760
> surf_Rebel_scaz_njv, Time: 00:22:07, Rank: 154/3513
> surf_reprise, Time: 01:10:95, Rank: 289/2005
> surf_rookie, Time: 03:07:88, Rank: 225/1869
> surf_simpsons_go_rc2, Time: 01:42:28, Rank: 344/3655
> surf_spacejam, Time: 01:25:20, Rank: 295/1870
> surf_sundown_njv, Time: 01:10:41, Rank: 36/138
> surf_the_gloaming, Time: 00:49:18, Rank: 49/367
> surf_trance_ksf, Time: 01:01:67, Rank: 332/1402
> surf_utopia_njv, Time: 00:51:66, Rank: 164/3041
> surf_water-run_banjo_skill, Time: 00:41:42, Rank: 127/4952
> surf_waterworks, Time: 01:27:01, Rank: 122/385
> surf_year3000, Time: 00:19:65, Rank: 467/1072
>
> ENEMY TIME:
> surf_ace_fix, Time: 00:51:92, Rank: 282/2635
> surf_aircontrol_ksf, Time: 00:44:00, Rank: 228/8792
> surf_akai_final, Time: 00:45:29, Rank: 125/2313
> surf_amplitude_light, Time: 01:17:37, Rank: 18/48
> surf_and_destroy, Time: 00:36:18, Rank: 50/494
> surf_annoyance_njv, Time: 06:33:09, Rank: 23/47
> surf_autism, Time: 00:42:56, Rank: 45/403
> surf_aweles, Time: 00:48:70, Rank: 40/215
> surf_beginner, Time: 00:49:86, Rank: 179/5116
> surf_borderlands, Time: 01:45:48, Rank: 48/232
> surf_calycate2, Time: 00:55:37, Rank: 29/104
> surf_calycate_csgo, Time: 00:37:11, Rank: 59/519
> surf_classics, Time: 19:12:39, Rank: 313/710
> surf_colors_beta1, Time: 01:36:25, Rank: 18/146
> surf_colours, Time: 02:06:84, Rank: 207/2189
> surf_colum_up, Time: 00:34:20, Rank: 38/1060
> surf_delusional_, Time: 01:51:07, Rank: 60/169
> surf_derpis_ksf, Time: 01:22:32, Rank: 111/3672
> surf_eclipse, Time: 03:02:91, Rank: 96/109
> surf_ethereal, Time: 01:14:97, Rank: 152/368
> surf_forbidden_ways_ksf, Time: 01:18:02, Rank: 203/1056
> surf_funhouse_njv, Time: 01:07:65, Rank: 83/927
> surf_grassland, Time: 00:47:44, Rank: 117/597
> surf_how2surf, Time: 01:29:08, Rank: 18/317
> surf_hurrr, Time: 00:42:82, Rank: 12/71
> surf_kitsune, Time: 01:13:30, Rank: 254/3654
> surf_kz_protraining, Time: 03:47:93, Rank: 31/181
> surf_leet_xl_beta7z_, Time: 00:16:91, Rank: 187/6755
> surf_legends_lite_gfl, Time: 00:32:23, Rank: 59/1676
> surf_lessons, Time: 00:50:43, Rank: 84/1397
> surf_life_of_duck_go, Time: 00:49:16, Rank: 103/3080
> surf_lullaby_ksf, Time: 01:05:30, Rank: 164/676
> surf_lux, Time: 00:36:43, Rank: 196/2668
> surf_me, Time: 02:14:60, Rank: 29/236
> surf_mesa, Time: 00:55:18, Rank: 262/6575
> surf_minuet_v1p, Time: 00:46:72, Rank: 163/1434
> surf_mom, Time: 00:49:26, Rank: 193/2960
> surf_neo_njv, Time: 00:45:87, Rank: 58/74
> surf_network_2008_final, Time: 00:37:66, Rank: 15/109
> surf_newb_hazard_r1, Time: 00:22:68, Rank: 71/992
> surf_noob, Time: 00:26:77, Rank: 17/74
> surf_olympics_sns, Time: 02:33:59, Rank: 46/102
> surf_oma, Time: 00:53:96, Rank: 12/96
> surf_pox, Time: 00:30:85, Rank: 82/2086
> surf_prelude_ksf, Time: 00:51:30, Rank: 155/611
> surf_presmon_fix, Time: 01:02:06, Rank: 13/68
> surf_prime_time_r3vamp, Time: 00:14:00, Rank: 76/2091
> surf_rebel_resistance_njv, Time: 00:26:34, Rank: 145/4760
> surf_Rebel_scaz_njv, Time: 00:20:83, Rank: 67/3513
> surf_reprise, Time: 01:10:05, Rank: 231/2005
> surf_rookie, Time: 02:51:45, Rank: 96/1869
> surf_simpsons_go_rc2, Time: 01:35:49, Rank: 178/3655
> surf_spacejam, Time: 01:19:81, Rank: 117/1870
> surf_sundown_njv, Time: 01:09:79, Rank: 34/138
> surf_the_gloaming, Time: 00:50:81, Rank: 86/367
> surf_trance_ksf, Time: 00:54:35, Rank: 141/1402
> surf_utopia_njv, Time: 00:51:70, Rank: 165/3041
> surf_water-run_banjo_skill, Time: 00:41:21, Rank: 118/4952
> surf_waterworks, Time: 01:26:20, Rank: 101/385
> surf_year3000, Time: 00:19:12, Rank: 332/1072
> ```

Comment: Off topic question: is this a community server feature?

Comment: @HassanAlthaf I'm not sure if it is. As I do not play CS:GO my acquaintance only asked me if I could create a map comparison with the data he has provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty tough for yourself: your code is not so bad (and surely not "REALLY sloppy" :) even if, yes, it can be improved.

Essentially it can be reduced, increasing readability at the same time, taking advantage of a few points:

- when not used elsewhere, intermediate variables can often be suppressed, using a bit more compounded statements
- something like `array_push($array, $data);` can be more simply replaced by `$array[] = $data;`
- due to the above, initializing the $array is not needed: it's implicitly created by the 1st setting

So this whole sequence:

```
$yourTimeTot = [];
$enemyTimeTot = [];
if (isset($_POST['subCompare'])) {
    $timeList = trim($_POST['yTime']);
    $timeList = explode("\n", $timeList);
    $timeList2 = trim($_POST['eTime']);
    $timeList2 = explode("\n", $timeList2);
    foreach ($timeList as $time) {
        $partials = explode(", ", $time);
        array_push($yourTimeTot, $partials);
    }
    foreach ($timeList2 as $time) {
        $partials = explode(", ", $time);
        array_push($enemyTimeTot, $partials);
    }
}
```

can be reduced to:

```
if (isset($_POST['subCompare'])) {
    foreach (explode("\n", trim($_POST['yTime'])) as $time) {
        $yourTimeTot[] = explode(',', $time);
    }
    foreach (explode("\n", trim($_POST['eTime'])) as $time) {
        $enemyTimeTot[] = explode(',', $time);
    }
}
```

As a rule of thumb, in something like `for ($j = 0; $j < count($yourTimeTot); $j++)`, you must realize that `count($yourTimeTot)` will be evaluated *at each step*: it's as much time consumer as much steps are to processed.
So you should rather write `for ($j = 0, $count = count($yourTimeTot); $j < $count; $j++)`: this way `$count` is evaluated only once.

BTW just a remark, though without great importance: `$enemTime` is a bit surprising and you might use `$enemyTime` instead.
I suspect your choice was guided by the fact that, located just under `$yourTime` the 1st time it appears, this made the two lines begin aligned. But I don't think it's worth it, with respect to the confusion it brings in the following.
(anyway, with my proposed change below it doesn't matter since this variable doesn't exist any longer)

When computing the time difference you work a lot, left-adding zeroes, to ensure it will always be 6 digits long, whatever its value.
This can be made with only one statement, using `str_pad()`.

Last point, you're printing each result with two statements like `echo "You win by: " . $timeZ . "<br>";`, where only `Enemy wins` replaces `You win` in the 2nd one.
Keeping concerned by DRYing, we can also prefer to use only one statement here.

Actually, taking in account these latter points in addition to the above ones, this sequence:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($yourTimeTot); $j++) {
    $yourTime = str_replace(":", "", substr($yourTimeTot[$j][1], 6));
    $enemTime = str_replace(":", "", substr($enemyTimeTot[$j][1], 6));

    $ext = "";
    $lenStr = strlen(str_replace("-", "", ($enemTime - $yourTime)));
    if ($lenStr != 6) {
        for ($k = $lenStr; $k != 6; $k++) {
            $ext .= "0";
        }
    }

    $z = $ext . str_replace("-", "", ($enemTime - $yourTime));
    $z = str_split($z, 2);

    $timeZ = implode(":", $z);
    if (($yourTime - $enemTime) < 0) {
        echo "You win by: " . $timeZ . "<br>";
        $yWin += 1;
    } else {
        echo "Enemy wins by: " . $timeZ . "<br>";
        $eWin += 1;
    }
}
```

can be reduced to:

```
for ($j = 0, $count = count($yourTimeTot); $j < $count; $j++) {
    $delta =
      str_replace(":", "", substr($yourTimeTot[$j][1], 6))
      - str_replace(":", "", substr($enemyTimeTot[$j][1], 6));
    if ($delta < 0) {
        $winner = 'You win';
        $yWin += 1;
    } else {
        $winner = 'Enemy wins';
        $eWin += 1;
    }
    echo $winner . ' by: ' .
      implode(':', str_split(str_pad(abs($delta), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), 2)) .
      '<br />';
}
```

Apart from these improvements, two points puzzle me:

1. You're *always* computing and printing results from `$YourTimeTot` and `$enemyTimeTot`, while those where populated *only* if `$_POST['subCompare']` is set.
   This is likely erroneous and you should have *the whole process* under the latter condition.
2. Schematically, each result is evaluated like this `if (you - enemy > 0) {you win} else {enemy wins}`.
   So what about `you == enemy`?
   (and note that currently this equality gives `enemy wins`)